Connect Spring Boot application to multiple Azure Event Hubs
So i have a SB app that is trying to integrate with a few event hubs to consume and also produce messages.
Reading the Microsoft documentation here i chose the Use Spring Messaging Azure Event Hubs choice.
I have added all the necessary properties to my application.properties file:
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.namespace=myHubUrl
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.event-hub-name=muHubName
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.connection-string=myHubConnectionString
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.processor.checkpoint-store.account-name=nameOfTheCheckpointAccount
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.processor.checkpoint-store.container-name=checkpointContainer
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.processor.checkpoint-store.connection-string=checkpointConnectionString
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.processor.consumer-group=myAppConsumerGroup

My Consumer Class:
@Component
public class EventHubConsumer {



    @EventHubsListener(destination = "${spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.event-hub-name}", group = "${spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.processor.consumer-group}")
    public void handleMessageFromEventHub(Object message) {
        LOGGER.info("Received message.");
    }
}

And my producer class:
@Component
public class EventHubProducer {  

    private final EventHubsTemplate eventHubsTemplate;
    private final String eventHubName;


    public EventHubProducer(EventHubsTemplate eventHubsTemplate,
                                  @Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.event-hub-name}") String eventHubName) {
        this.eventHubsTemplate = eventHubsTemplate;
        this.eventHubName = eventHubName;
    }

    public void writeEvent(Object object){
        LOGGER.info("Sending message to Hub...");

        eventHubsTemplate.send(eventHubName, MessageBuilder.withPayload(object).build());
    }

Now, all of this works totally fine, I can read and write to the event hub which's connection string and namespace I've provided.
The problem comes when I am trying to add another Event Hub in the mix, which might have it's own namespace and/or connection string, and this credentials are processed in the background(the Azure library). I haven't found a good way to provide that in my application.properties so that it would work the same as the situation above. Also I'm not sure if i should provide a second blob storage for the additional event hub.
I'm sure there must be a way, and it should be straight forward, but I'm just unable to make it work. Any ideas?
Big thanks!

Have you tried adding another Event Hub in the application.properties?

@DasariKamali  Yes, but i am not sure what is the property where i should add the second connection string.

Can you share the GitHub repo?

Unfortunately I can not. But i only have the PoC above, no other logic

Could you use the kafka libraries (spring-kafka) instead of the azure one or you must stay with that?

I guess i could, but the kafka library has no support for the checkpoint blob storage azure needs, so that might be a blocker.

I successfully sent and received the messages to the Azure Event Hubs using the below Spring Boot application.
EventHubProducerService.java :
package com.example.EventHubs.service;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventData;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubProducerClient;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventDataBatch;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EventHubProducerService {

    private static final String EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_1 = "<Hub1_ConneString>";
    private static final String EVENT_HUB_NAME_1 = "<hub1Name>";
    private static final String EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_2 = "<Hub2_ConneString>";
    private static final String EVENT_HUB_NAME_2 = "<hub2Name>";

    public void sendMessages() {
        try (EventHubProducerClient producerClient1 = new EventHubClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_1, EVENT_HUB_NAME_1)
                .buildProducerClient();
             EventHubProducerClient producerClient2 = new EventHubClientBuilder()
                     .connectionString(EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_2, EVENT_HUB_NAME_2)
                     .buildProducerClient()) {
            EventDataBatch eventDataBatch1 = producerClient1.createBatch();
            eventDataBatch1.tryAdd(new EventData("First event for Event Hub 1"));
            producerClient1.send(eventDataBatch1);
            EventDataBatch eventDataBatch2 = producerClient2.createBatch();
            eventDataBatch2.tryAdd(new EventData("First event for Event Hub 2"));
            producerClient2.send(eventDataBatch2);
            System.out.println("Messages sent successfully to both Event Hubs.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

EventHubReceiverService.java :
package com.example.EventHubs.service;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubConsumerAsyncClient;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder;
import com.azure.core.util.BinaryData;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class EventHubReceiverService {

    private static final String EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_1 = "<Hub1_ConneString>";
    private static final String EVENT_HUB_NAME_1 = "<hub1Name>";
    private static final String CONSUMER_GROUP_1 = "$Default";
    private static final String EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_2 = "<Hub2_ConneString>";
    private static final String EVENT_HUB_NAME_2 = "<hub2Name>";
    private static final String CONSUMER_GROUP_2 = "$Default";
    private static final String BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = "<storageConneString>";
    private static final String BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = "<containerName?";
    private BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient;

    public EventHubReceiverService() {
        this.blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)
                .containerName(BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
                .buildClient();
    }
    public void receiveMessages() {
        EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumerClient1 = new EventHubClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_1, EVENT_HUB_NAME_1)
                .consumerGroup(CONSUMER_GROUP_1)
                .buildAsyncConsumerClient();
        EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumerClient2 = new EventHubClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR_2, EVENT_HUB_NAME_2)
                .consumerGroup(CONSUMER_GROUP_2)
                .buildAsyncConsumerClient();
        consumerClient1.receive()
                .subscribe(event -> {
                    String message = event.getData().getBodyAsString();
                    System.out.printf("Received from Event Hub 1: %s%n", message);
                    storeMessageInBlobStorage("EventHub1", message);
                }, error -> {
                    System.err.println("Error receiving from Event Hub 1: " + error);
                });
        consumerClient2.receive()
                .subscribe(event -> {
                    String message = event.getData().getBodyAsString();
                    System.out.printf("Received from Event Hub 2: %s%n", message);
                    storeMessageInBlobStorage("EventHub2", message);
                }, error -> {
                    System.err.println("Error receiving from Event Hub 2: " + error);
                });
    }
    private void storeMessageInBlobStorage(String source, String message) {
        String blobName = source + "/" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".txt";
        blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(blobName)
                .upload(BinaryData.fromString(message), true);
        System.out.printf("Stored message in Blob Storage: %s%n", blobName);
    }
}

EventHubController.java :
package com.example.EventHubs.controller;
import com.example.EventHubs.service.EventHubProducerService;
import com.example.EventHubs.service.EventHubReceiverService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class EventHubController {

    private final EventHubProducerService producerService;
    private final EventHubReceiverService receiverService;
    public EventHubController(EventHubProducerService producerService, EventHubReceiverService receiverService) {
        this.producerService = producerService;
        this.receiverService = receiverService;
    }
    @GetMapping("/send")
    public String sendMessages() {
        producerService.sendMessages();
        return "Messages sent!";
    }
    @GetMapping("/receive")
    public String receiveMessages() {
        receiverService.receiveMessages();
        return "Receiving messages. Check console output.";
    }
}

pom.xml :
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventhubs</artifactId>
        <version>5.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>12.17.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Output :
I have sent the messages to Azure Event Hubs using the below URL in the browser.
http://localhost:8080/send



I have received the messages from Azure Event Hubs using the below URL in the browser.
http://localhost:8080/receive




Yep. This works, I created something similar in the meantime. Programatic method paid off :)

@TudorCheregi I'm glad it worked.
